# Angular 2 change data from class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, typescript, angular

Why I can't change data in View from function in class?

wrap.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'wrap',
    templateUrl: './templates/wrap.html'
})

export class WrapComponent {
    public test: string;
    constructor () {
        this.test = 'Hello world';
    }

    fun () {
        this.test = 'SPAM';
    }
}
```

express.component.ts

```
import {WrapComponent} from './wrap.component';
export class Express {
    constructor () {
        new WrapComponent().fun();
    }
}
```

wrap.html

```
<h2>{{test}}</h2>
```

Why in view test variable is 'Hello world'?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you instantiate by your own the `WrapComponent` component from the `Express` class. Angular2 manages by itself component instances. This means that you don't share the same instance.

To help you further, I need to know which kind of entity the `Express` class represents... Another component, a service, ...

You could call the `fun` method from a `click` event within the `WrapComponent` component:

```
<div (click)="fun()">Have fun!</div>
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Full application work as electron app, and in full version `Express` is class with ExpressJS API. Then this api get request, I run method `fun`. This method locate in other file `wrap.components.ts`, which have component and front-end business logic. This method must change data in `wrap.html`.